# Handling sql mirroring connectivity in client .net application

Tags: c#, sql-server, mirroring

so ive been playing around setting up a sql mirror with high availability in sql server 2008, but im confused as to handle connectivity from client apps.  Say i have a simple website that connects to the principal and displays employees name.  If the principal goes offline / down and the mirror is set as a the new principal by the witness, how does the client app still connect as the connection string will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the FailoverPartner attribute in your connection string.  There is a good outline [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175484.aspx).